# Start application with administrative privileges when user logs on

Tags: vb.net, uac

I'm trying to find a way to start an application when the user logs on. The application must have administrative privileges.

This seems to be easy: just create a new registry key under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

This works, but the user is asked every time by the **User Account Control** window. This is annoying, especially at startup. So I'm trying to find a way to launch this applications with elevated privileges but without the UAC prompt.

I've found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html) a solution: it uses **Windows Task Scheduler**. However, this Windows utility seems a bit unreliabled: sometimes it works well, sometimes not. On two computer tested, my application is started with a delay average of **46 seconds**.

On the link given below, it says that you can recall the Task Scheduler operation with this command (where *MyOperationName* is the name of the scheduled task):

```
schtasks /run /tn "MyOperationName"
```

so, if I try to combine this command to a new key in CurrentVersion\Run I should get what I want. Would this work?

I'm working on VB.NET WinForms, Visual Studio 2013 and I use [this](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) library to interoperate with Task Scheduler.

Thanks,

*FWhite*

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for a service.  UAC is a user protection.  Trying to do an end run around it sounds like an ill-conceived idea.

Comment: Well, it isn't. Would you be happy to have to click on "Yes" every time you start your computer, and maybe you're in a hurry? However, I agree with you on a point: if I were a user, I wouldn't like any program to do important things without my consent. Indeed, I'm going to ask the user if they want to run my program, but only once (during the program setup, not every time they start their computer).